# TileEntitySpecialRenderer only renders from certain angle

Tags: java, rendering, minecraft-modding

I'm developing a Minecraft mod with Forge. I've added a tileentity and a custom renderer for it. The problem is: The block is only visible from sertain angles. I've compaed my code to other peoples code and it looks pretty much like them.

The block is opaque and not to be rendered and the renderer is registered normally so the fault must be in the renderer.

Here's the renderer code:

```
public class TERender extends TileEntitySpecialRenderer
{
    public void renderTileEntityAt(TileEntity tileEntity, double d, double d1, double d2, float f)
    {
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        GL11.glTranslatef((float)d, (float)d1, (float)d2);
        HeatConductTileEntity TE = (HeatConductTileEntity)tileEntity;
        renderBlock(TE, tileEntity.getWorldObj(), tileEntity.xCoord, tileEntity.yCoord, tileEntity.zCoord, mod.EMHeatConductor);
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
    }

    public void renderBlock(HeatConductTileEntity tl, World world, int i, int j, int k, Block block)
    {    
        Tessellator tessellator = Tessellator.instance;
        GL11.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        tessellator.startDrawingQuads();
        tessellator.addVertex(0, 0, 0);
        tessellator.addVertex(1, 0, 0);
        tessellator.addVertex(1, 1, 0);
        tessellator.addVertex(0, 1, 0);
        tessellator.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, so I won't make it an answer yet, but try drawing two quads, where the second has the same vertices in the opposite order. If it works, then your problem is backface culling, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595087/opengl-newbie-question-what-is-back-face-culling

Comment: Tried it also with openGL. I drew lines instead. Same effect.

Comment: OpenGL has (almost) nothing to do with it. If backface culling is enabled, a triangle will only be drawn if it's facing the camera. When the triangle is facing away from the camera, it won't be drawn. And usually the order vertices are declared is what is used to determine which way the triangle is "facing".

Comment: Not so simple. The colour keeps changin and it's visibility is pretty much random. I can't see it from the back side, but I know that's normal.

Comment: Got it, so your problem really is unusual. I don't have an answer for it, though.

Comment: Also a sollution on how to use normal openGL would be nice. Even that acts abit weird in the same way.

Comment: What happens if you manually draw two triangles, instead of using the tessellator?

Comment: The colour is OK, but it is only visible from some angles and distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if you want to render only colour, but not texture you have to disable GL_TEXTURE_2D

Comment: This was exactly the issue I was having! I figured I would get the rendering working before I worried about textures and this was driving me crazy! I just wish I could +1 more than once.